# Detect change in hidden input[type="file"]

Tags: jquery, input, onchange, hidden

I have a hidden input[type=file] and a separate button which triggers click on this hidden input. How can I detect the value change in this hidden input, i.e, when the user has selected a file?

```
<form id="photo_upload_form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <button >Upload a Photo</button>
    <input name="file" type="file" hidden />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#photo_upload_form button').click(function(){
        $('input[type="file"]').trigger('click');
});
$('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
    alert('Change !');
});
```

EDIT: My button click submits the form so I had to use a preventDefault !

Comment: You can use a mutation observer

Comment: Is there a simple solution for it? If somehow I can trigger change?

Comment: Can you show us/explain to us what you have tried so far to achieve what you are wanting?

Comment: I just used the .change() function. Everything works fine if I dont hide the input field ! Once I do, it doesn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c5e836gn/2/ - seems fine

Comment: The button submits the form ! My bad !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) for `input[type=“file”]`

```
<input type="file" onchange="myFunction()">
```

here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/qs4y0rLe/

as your code, change like below

```
 $('input[type="file"]').on('change',function(){
            alert('Change !');
    });
```

about jquery `.on()`, attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements. more --> http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://jsfiddle.net/qs4y0rLe/1/

Comment: It is a hidden input field, so the change doesn't automatically trigger, right?

Comment: @user3142839 what you mean hidden input[type=file]?? display:none; or type="hidden" ?

Comment: <input type="file" hidden> or display: none for that matter

Comment: @user3142839 i upgraded my answer, check it

Comment: @user3142839 upgraded my answer

Comment: The button submits the form so I'll have to use a e.preventDefault(). My bad !

Comment: This helped me a lot too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It will still trigger change event on the input[type=file], sth like

```
$("input[type=file]").on('change',function() {});
```

Comment: @user3142839 what about `visibility: hidden`